# Ajax String Success Parse not the same as hard coding the string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

If I hard-code this, everything is as expected:

```
var bytes = Utf8.parse('myString');
```

But this does return the same string as above.

```
var temp = String(getMyString());
var bytes = Utf8.parse(temp)
```

Here is my ajax call that calls the next code block.

```
    function getMyString() {
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'post',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url: '/Controller/GetString',
            success: function (response) {
                var obj = JSON.parse(response.Success);
                return obj;
            }
        });
    }
```

My Controller Calls the Next Code Block.

```
    public JsonResult GetString()
    {
        var s = myClass.GetMyString();
        return Json(new { Success = s });
    }
```

In a static class

```
public static string GetMyString()
{            
    return "myString";
}
```

The End result is a thrown exception because the Byte array is off, because the input string is somehow not the same.  I thought a async controller might be to blame, so that is my next attempt.

Comment: What are you using `JSON.parse`? Should be just `var obj = response.Success`

Comment: I tried that and it is producing the same result.  Called response.Success.toString(), tried '' + response.Success.

Comment: What result? You have not explained what the result is in either case.

Comment: Byte array is not the same from the inputs.  I edited my post.

Comment: And what is `Utf8.parse()`? What plugin are you using?

Comment: Your `temp` is empty, since `getMyString()` doesn't return anything. Once again this is a ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)